# Copy HTML Content as RTF format in kendo ui text editor

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I Am trying to copy from kendo ui text editor to WPF text box, all text formatting is not available in WPF text box, is there any way to copy content as RTF.

Thanks